# How do i fix this error: localhost/:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found), Cannot Get /

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm creating an online multiplayer .io game similar to https://diep.io/ or https://agar.io/ and I'm in the process of setting up a server this is my code,

```
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http'); 
var express = require('express'); 
var socketIO = require('socket.io'); 

var publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../client');
var port = process.env.PORT || 2000;
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketIO(server);
app.use(express.static(publicPath));

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server stared on port ' + port);

});
```

When I start the server and put "localhost:2000" into the search bar this is what comes up,

[image]

I'm kinda new to this so if you could make the answers simple to understand then I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: What do you expect it to respond with? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Double check your paths. Your code will work as written if you have a folder structure like so:

```
/server/index.js
/client/index.html
```

`$ node server/index.js`

The static middleware by default will serve files which match html, html.
So if you have index.html, you can make a request to `/`, and if you have hello.html, you can hit it at /hello.

See here for more options: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html

Note: this middleware is what `Express.static` uses, so no need to install that package, just look at examples for `serveStatic()` and pass those to Express' version.